# Calculate updated value based on a column

Tags: scala, slick

Can Slick produce an SQL statement that performs an update that updates a column based on another column? I want to achieve something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = (col2 + 5) WHERE col3 = "Foo"
```

I looked into `Query.mutate()`, but my understanding is that the computation will be performed at the client side (and not on the database server).

I wish it was something like:

```
Query(table).updateV2 { r => (r.col1 -> r.col2 + 5) }
```

Is there anyway to achieve this in Slick without composing raw queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not supported in the typesafe API. We have a ticket to add it some time in the future.

https://www.assembla.com/spaces/typesafe-slick/tickets/298-mutating-updates--update-foo-set-a-a+123

For now you could use a transaction with a select and subsequent update. Or plain SQL.